# Is it possible to use libraries while being lightweight and cross platform compatible?

Tags: c++, boost

I've got a small C++ project to which I'd like to add the ability to detect existence of a folder and create one if it does not exist. The method I've dug up requires Boost Filesystem, however I'm unclear as to how to keep my project small, simple and cross-platform.

The main issue is that Filesystem requires me to link against a library object, this is obviously not cross platform. I do not want to require my users to install the Boost library themselves and it's clearly impractical to distribute Boost inside my own project.

I am considering two options:

1. Somehow pull out only the files relevant for Filesystem from the Boost library and hopefully that's small enough to package with my project. Though I have no idea how I could identify which files are required.
2. Distribute binaries only. I don't know if this is possible without greatly expanding my workflow, I currently work simply in VSCode and Terminal on macOS. What are the considerations for multi-platform distribution? Do I need a binary for each OS, 32/64bit and CPU? Are cross-platform compilations using march and mcpu reliable?

Please also let me know if I've greatly misunderstood the nature of my problem.

Comment: Take a look at the std::filesystem library coming soon to a C++ near you.

Comment: As I understand this requires users to have the most cutting edge version of gcc/clang? I do make use for C++11 but I'm reluctant to even require c++14.

Comment: Reasonable concerns. How many platforms need you support? It may be simpler to write a small portability layer of your own and configure the makefile to detect the target and compile and link the appropriate cpp file for the target.

Comment: It's for bioinformatics, which means different flavours of Linux, at the bare minimum I'd need need to support macOS, Ubuntu and centOS. But ideally anything apart from Windows should be supported (file path incompatibility). Are you suggesting I compile the boost_filesystem.a for each of my target systems and bundle them all with my package with conditional flags using make?

Comment: What I'm suggesting is you have 1 header that exports the `detectAndCreateFolder` function, 2-3 cpp files defining `detectAndCreateFolder` for POSIX-based systems (Linux, Unix and, I think, Mac), Windows-based systems, and maybe one using C++17, and either build instructions telling the user to pick one or a makefile that has the smarts to pick, build, and link the correct cpp file for the target system.

Comment: I would recommend proposed Boost.AFIO which provides async filesystem and file i/o, but alas it has a hard dependency on Filesystem too.

Comment: @user3481301 If you are referring to cpp files then there's no need for portability layer, I can just code it to be portable. The non-portable part right now is the libboost_filesystem.a, this is from what I understand contains machine code specific to my OS and architecture.